# Spring boot OAuth2 custom roles on Resource server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

**TL;DR:** How to assign users custom roles/authorities on Resource server side (that means without JWT) based on their access_token?

**The whole story:** I have a working Auth server and a client (which is SPA), which can obtain access_token from the Auth server. With that access_token the client can request data on my Resource server (which is separated from Auth server). The Resource server can get username from Auth server using the access_token.

I can access the username in code by injection `Authentication` object into method like this:

```kotlin
@RequestMapping("/ping")
fun pingPong(auth: Authentication): String = "pong, " + auth.name
```

My question is how to add my custom roles or authorities (`auth.authorities` - there is only USER_ROLE) to this object which would be managed on the Resource server, not Auth server, based on the username.

I have tried several ways to do it but none has helped. The most promising was this:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
class ResourceServerConfigurer(val userDetailsService: MyUserDetailsService) : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService) // userDetailsService is autowired
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
    }
}
```

And my custom UserDetailsService:

```kotlin
@Service
class UserDetailsService : org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String): UserDetails {
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(username, "password", getAuthorities(username))

    }

    private fun getAuthorities(user: String): Set<GrantedAuthority> {
        val authorities = HashSet<GrantedAuthority>()
        authorities.addAll(listOf(
                SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ONE"),  //let's grant some roles to everyone
                SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TWO")))
        return authorities
    }
}
```

Everything worked (I mean I was successfully authenticated) except that I still had only ROLE_USER. Next what I tried was providing a custom implementation of AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun authenticationProvider(): AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    return object : AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider() {
        override fun retrieveUser(username: String, authentication: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken): UserDetails {
            return User(username, "password", getAuthorities(username))

        }

        private fun getAuthorities(user: String): Set<GrantedAuthority> {
            val authorities = HashSet<GrantedAuthority>()
            authorities.addAll(listOf(
                    SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ONE"),
                    SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TWO")))
            return authorities
        }

        override fun additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails: UserDetails, authentication: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken?) {
        }
    }
}
```

with same result, only the ROLE_USER was present.

I would really appreciate any ideas from you guys how add some roles to the Authentication object after the access_token was validated and username obtained from Auth server.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Solution by OP.*

First of all I needed to provide custom `PrincipalExtractor` and `AuthoritiesExtractor` implementations. But to make Spring use them it is necessary in configuration NOT to use `security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri` but `security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri` instead (I really didn't expect this to be one of the roots of my problem).
Finally the security config must be done in `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`, not in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

The final code looks like this:

```kotlin
    @SpringBootApplication
    @RestController
    class MyApplication {
    
        @RequestMapping("/ping")
        fun pingPong(user: Authentication): String {
            return "pong, " + user.name + " - " + user.authorities.joinToString()
        }
    }
    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableResourceServer
    class ResourceServerConfigurer : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
    
        override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
            http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/index.html").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
        }
    
        @Bean
        fun principalExtractor() = PrincipalExtractor {
            return@PrincipalExtractor it["name"]
        }
    
        @Bean
        fun authoritiesExtractor() = AuthoritiesExtractor {
            return@AuthoritiesExtractor AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_ONE,ROLE_TWO")
        }
    }
    
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `CustomAuthenticationConverter` to get the roles

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration {
    
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String authServerBaseUrl;
    
    interface Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter extends Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {
    }

    List<String> publicApis = List.of("/login", "/rest/**", "/token", 
             "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/vendor/**", "/favicon.ico");
     
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        http.anonymous().disable();       
        http.cors().and().authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(publicApis.stream()
                        .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
                        .toArray(RequestMatcher[]::new)).permitAll()
            
                .anyRequest().authenticated()).csrf().disable();
            
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                        .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomAuthenticationConverter())
                    )
                );
    
              
        return http.build();
    }
  
    static class CustomAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
        public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
            Collection<String> authorities = jwt.getClaimAsStringList("roles");
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = authorities.stream()
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, grantedAuthorities);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can get the role :

```
Authentication authentication = getAuthentication();
authentication.getAuthorities()
```

Refer:-

Authorization server -> https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-authorization-server/

Resource server -> https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-resource-server https://github.com/m-thirumal/oauth-resource-server