# Spring Boot JWT : Forbidden 403 error for GET API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, http-status-code-403

I am learning to implement JWT authentication for my endpoints.
I am able to generate JWT code successfully using POST call.
But facing problem with authenticating simple GET API in SecurityConfig Class. Looking forward for some help.
Been stuck on this issue for 2 days, Could not find anything on this.

I configured the Logs on Debug mode and found below error as well. I could not find any proper solution for it on existing stack-overflow threads.

```
DEBUG 8196 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header        
java.io.EOFException: null
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:795) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:359) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

Error : GET API

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-11-22T17:20:57.227+00:00",
"status": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "",
"path": "/hello"
```

}

SecurityConfig.class

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/hello").authenticated().and()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Uploaded my code to Repo for better reference.
https://github.com/rohit-shinde/spring-jwt-tutorial

Comment: When you call the ```GET /hello```, do you have a headeer like ```Authorizataion: Bearer <the jwt token>```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a small typo in `JwtRequestFilter.java -> doFilterInternal -> line 44`

I think you meant this:

```
...
        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(jwtUtils.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
...
```

or perhaps:

```
...
        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(jwtUtils.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
...
```

Notice I changed `SecurityContextHolder.getContext() == null` to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null` in the first snippet. In the second snippet I changed it to `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null`.

Accoriding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288854/authentication-is-null-on-the-securitycontextholder-getcontext), `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` should not be null.

Comment: thanks, It did work, But I am not clear on why it worked with notequal, The Equalto Null checks is used to check if the incoming request does not have anything in its security context, then I could validate jwt and set the security context on my own.

Comment: @Rohit I think the security context already exists, but the ```authentication``` property is null. I changed the answer to include use this check as well ```SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null```.